# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the... right syntax to use near '"category =

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a little stuck with an update query. I've tried alternative syntaxes, but I'm still getting the *same* error.

```
$itemName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['itemName']);
$itemDescription = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['itemDescription']);
$itemCategory = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['itemCategory']);

if(isset($_POST['itemPrice']))
    $itemPrice = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['itemPrice']);

$statement = 'update products set "category = ' .
$itemCategory.', price = "'. 
$itemPrice .'", product = "' . 
$itemName . '", description = "' . 
$itemDescription . '" where id = "' . 
$itemId . '"';

if(mysqli_query($db, $statement))
{
    $kittehHasError = false;
    $message = $itemName . " has been updated successfully.";
}
else
{
    $kittehHasError = true;
    $message = "Something went wrong: " . mysqli_error($db);
}

<p><? echo $message ?></p>
```

The error I receive is:

> Something went wrong: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '"category = games, price = "60.75", product =
>   "Wildstar", description = "Ongoing' at line 1

What am I doing wrong? I have set breakpoints and all the values are holding data and the correct data. So I'm not sure why the query isn't working. I thought that maybe it was because the *description* contains single quotes, however, when adding MySQL_real_escape_string() I still receive the same error.

Comment: Copy the resulted query and try it directly in the SQL client. Then try changing the suspicious parts until it works. Once it works there, you will know how to construct it in PHP as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
  $statement = 'update products set "category = ' .
  $itemCategory.', price = "'.
```

to

```
  $statement = 'update products set category = "'.
  $itemCategory.'", price = "'.
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it still doesn't work; that was my original syntax, I still get the same error: `Something went wrong: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"category = "games", price = "666.00", product = "Wildstar", description = "Ongo' at line 1`

Comment: Please read my answer once again, double quote near `category` is wrong

Comment: PHP is not outputting the exact code which I believe is causing confusion. I did try your code on the bottom half of your answer. Still results in the error.

Comment: WTH? How did that get there!

Comment: Omg, I can't believe I overlooked that after reading it a thousand times. Thank you @Akshay.

Answer (score 0):

Your query have the issue. Replace your with the below code:

```
$statement = 'update products set category = "' .$itemCategory.'", 
   price = "'. $itemPrice .'", 
   product = "' . $itemName . '", 
   description = "' . $itemDescription . '" 
   where id = "' . $itemId . '"';
```

You have an unnecessary Comma before `category`. I think it should be in the value part.

Try above code.

Comment: thank you but that was my original syntax, and it still results in the same error: `Something went wrong: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"category = "games", price = "666.00", product = "Wildstar", description = "Ongo' at line 1`

Comment: @PIJNSO678 see the error you have not remove comma before `'"category = "gam` .. I think you have not used my code and without using it you are saying that. check the answer and try.